# React-native Firebase Firestore - NSException raise:format:arguments

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

The error occurs approximately 60 times a day with approximately 200 users a day. I cannot repeat it myself during tests. Here is screenshot of the error:

[image]

And below is an expansion of lines that cannot be seen:

```
#3 (null) in -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] ()

#4 (null) in                    0x10430ddc4 firebase::firestore::util::ObjcThrowHandler(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<ch... ()

#5 (null) in                    0x10430d998 firebase::firestore::util::Throw(firebase::firestore::util::ExceptionType, char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()

#6 (null) in                    0x10435c4f4 firebase::firestore::util::internal::FailAssertion(char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) ()

#7 (null) in                    0x10435c594 firebase::firestore::util::internal::FailAssertion(char const*, char const*, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) ()

#8 (null) in                    0x1043d08f0 firebase::firestore::core::Transaction::EnsureCommitNotCalled() ()

#9 (null) in                    0x1043d0680 firebase::firestore::core::Transaction::Lookup(std::__1::vector<firebase::firestore::model::DocumentKey, std::__1::allocator<firebase::firestore::model::DocumentKey> > const&, std::__1::function<vo... ()

#10 (null) in                    0x1043485b0 -[FIRTransaction getDocument:completion:] ()

#11 (null) in                    0x104348790 -[FIRTransaction getDocument:error:] ()

#12 (null) in                    0x104481198 -[RNFBFirestoreTransactionModule transactionGetDocument:::::] ()

#16 (null) in                    0x1044ebad8 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] ()

#17 (null) in                    0x1044edc5c facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) ()

#19 (null) in                    0x1044ed9c0 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) ()
```

I use `firestore().runTransaction` in foreground and background.

I can't find the answer whether the error is on my side or the Firebase libraries. Does anyone know what this error means and how to eliminate it?

Comment: The error may be caused by passing in your function an empty string as the document UID.
Without seeing your code I think it's not possible to tell certainly.

Comment: The problem is that there are several places in the application where it performs various operations on the firestore and I don't know where in the application it is. So I will try to check if I am actually putting an empty string somewhere in the document id

Comment: Hey @RadosławGajos, have you managed to fix this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is elsewhere. But I still don't know where ...